# how to include seconds in time format in full calendar?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar version 3.4.0 which I'm using in my .net website. But I'm only able to display the in time and out time in Hour and Minute time format.I'm not able to display the seconds in my full calendar.This is the code where I specify the time format for my Full calendar

```
 $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                        contentHeight: 500,
                        displayEventEnd: true,
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',

                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                        },
                        eventLimit: true,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        events: event_array,
```

In code the time format is specified as `timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a'` I have to include the seconds aswell.

Comment: Please specify what version of fullCalender js you are using??

Comment: Wouldn't something like `'h(:mm(:ss))a'` work? or even just `'h:mm:ss'`

Comment: Thanks @Rafalon 'h:mm:ss' works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used  `timeFormat: 'h:mm:ss a'` in my code and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the monument.js documentation when using date strings in fullCalendar.js

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/